# Build struct element with correct size

Tags: c++, struct, size, element

I am intercepting some packets, and then put them into an structure.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct PacketHeader {
    short Size;
    short Checksum;
    short Index;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

I have a packet with `PacketHeader` and some other bytes that fill this structure:

```
struct STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE {
    PacketHeader Header;
    unsigned char TitleLength; // 1 byte
    char* RoomTitle[23];
    short Unknow;
    short Unknow2;
    short Password1;
    short Password2;
    char LastByte;
};
```

In the above struct, TitleLength is one byte, that in decimal can 0x17 (23) or any number. This number the numbers of chars contained in RoomTitle.

I need to set size of `RoomTitle` accortng to `TitleLenght` byte (as decimal number).

How could I modify the struct to handle the text size in the right location inside the struct?

Comment: `char* RoomTitle[23]` It seems extremely unlikely that you will receive, over the network, 23 pointers that are valid in your process' address space. Did you mean `char RoomTitle[23]`?

Comment: You can't alter the definition of the structure at run-time. You have a variable-length message coming from the wire, you need to parse it accordingly. You can't define a single `struct` that would magically fit a message of any size. You can define structs for fixed-size parts of the message - for example, you can define `PacketFooter` for fields `Unknown` through `LastByte`. But you need to determine programmatically at what offset in the message `PacketFooter` begins.

Comment: PacketHeader is 6 bytes long. Then comes TitleLenght, and then RoomTitle starts exatly at byte 8. Could you give me an example of how to devide the struct and define the start offset ?

Comment: You can define one structure for `Header` through `RoomTitle`, and another for `Unknown` through `LastByte`. That second structure is at a variable offset - namely, `offsetof(FirstStructure, RoomTitle) + firstStructure->TitleLength`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like follows, to parse the `RoomTitle` from the packet received at your socket:

```
struct STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE {
    PacketHeader Header; // Header length is sizeof(PacketHeader)
    unsigned char TitleLength; // 1 byte
    char RoomTitle[255]; // I suspect you don't have 23 `RoomTitle[23];` char* 
                         // pointers at this point, but just a char* maximally 
                         // sized as the maximum number that TitleLength can hold 
                         // (which is 255).
    short Unknow; // Unknow length is sizeof(short)
    short Unknow2; // ... ditto aso.
    short Password1;
    short Password2;
    char LastByte;
};
```

As I pointed out in the code comments above

1. Read the `PacketHeader` (take care of `Size` and `CRC` endianess!)
2. Read the payload data according to `PacketHeader::Size` from the packet into another buffer. (Consider to check the CRC)
3. Read the `TitleLength` and `RoomTitle` from the payload data accordingly. Take care, if you want to handle the `RoomTitle` data as a c-style string, it's actually terminated with `'\0'`. Also use the `TitleLength` information when copying elsewhere.
4. Read the data with well known size coming after (take care of endianess again)

---

Some pseudo code (not tested):

```
int recv_ROOM_CREATE_packet(int sockfd, STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE* packet) {
    read(sockfd,&(packet->Header),sizeof(PacketHeader));
    read(sockfd,&(packet->TitleLength),sizeof(unsigned char));
    read(sockfd,packet->RoomTitle,packet->TitleLength);
    // ensure that packet->RoomTitle is a correctly terminated c-style string
    if(packet->TitleLength < 255) {
        packet->RoomTitle[packet->TitleLength + 1] = `\0`; 
    }
    else {
        packet->RoomTitle[254] = `\0`; 
    }
    // aso ...
}
```

Comment: I put PacketHeader inside this struct this way:
`STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE* RoomCreate = (STRUCT_SVC_ROOM_CREATE*)pHeader;`

Then I can get or set the elements `RoomCreate->RoomTitle;`

Comment: Should I put the text part out of the struct?

Comment: @ThiagoMarquezini You'll need a dynamic allocation to hold the `RoomTitle` part or an at least 255 byte holding buffer, yes.

Comment: Could you give me an example? o.o

Comment: @ThiagoMarquezini It's too complex to give you a concise example, unless you show some more of your actual code, how you parse these packets. The best I advice I can give is, to keep up with those steps given in my wanswer.

Comment: @ThiagoMarquezini I edited my answer a bit, forget about dynamic allocation in this case.